# What simple, non-trivial, usable code have you created in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to learn F#, but since I have never done any functional programming or taken a class in it, I find it very hard to generalize the trivial fibonacci or factorial examples into how I would do something usable.

So, what simple but nontrivial non-trivial and usable F# code is there on the net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use it whenever I have the need for parser support (nowadays you might call it DSL) and whenever I implement symbol-processing algorithms.

The latest productive code I've written in F# concerns filters (used to filter incomming messages to a logging service). I've got a couple of basic filters (that processes the subject, etc.) and higher-order logic filters that combine other filters with AND/OR/NOT operators.
The implementation simplifies such "expressions" by converting them to CNF, collecting by type and using special rules (like a < 5 && a < 10 => a < 5, etc.)
On top of this I createt a simple parser with fsyacc to give the users of this service a simpler way to create filters.

I guess the hole thing has in F# as many lines of code I would have needed with C# to write just the simplification ;)

Comment: may i ask how you accomplished the CNF conversion? handcrafted or using some library? which technique?

Comment: well this is quite some time (almost 5 years - wow time runs fast) ... if I remember correctly I did this by hand (should not be very hard) - basically it's described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form ... hope this helps

Comment: btw: nowadays I would not use fsyacc anymore - I would start with fparsec and only go to back if this would not yield enough speed

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a great session from PDC](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL11/) -- he does a fairly non-trivial example application.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is a really great and entertaining presentation. Impressive!

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of blogs with fun code samples; start at http://fsharp.net and follow the various community blogs and samples to dig up a bit of content.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a direct answer, but my advice: port some library from Haskell. You'll get some great, guaranteed functional code to read and write. It'll force you into a different mindset.

Examples:
[FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) and [FsCheck](http://fscheck.codeplex.com). Lots of candidates at [Hacakge](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html).

Alternatively work through the [Real World Haskell](http://www.realworldhaskell.org/) book and try to write some of the examples in F#.

Finally, check out [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com) and friends for things tagged with F#.

Comment: I am not sure if a guy who never programmed functional style before has a good start if he tries to port libraries from a language he cannot read into a language he tries to learn...

Comment: You're quite the pessimist aren't you? That's exactly what I did and I had good results.

Comment: The analogy of what you suggest is to say if asked how to best learn korean language as an american was to transcribe some chinese poems to korean. ;) Why would doubling your workload be of any help?

Comment: I'll ignore the strawman. It helps because the two languages are reasonably alike - they are both functional and this is the biggest hurdle; porting a project gives you a concrete goal of a decent size; porting code forces you to really understand the code you read; and understanding and comparing language choices gives you a much better viewpoint than just focussing on one. Minimizing the workload is the wrong goal when you're trying to learn something.

Comment: Korean and chinese are also alike. They both use funny glyphs for writing. But, while I am able to write code in F# I cannot even get the entry point in haskell right because of cryptic indentation rules. Then some say I should use delimiters and bracket blocks while others say I should not. Dude, haskell is a mess, f# is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

[Validating email addresses](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/04/email-validation-with-fparsec.html) with [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/)